# How to get a list of Hangfire recurring jobs in C# .Net 7?

Tags: c#, job-scheduling, hangfire

This seems straight forward but I can't get examples to work for whatever reason.

I am using Hangfire.Core 1.8.6. My connection is good because I can create one-off and recurring jobs that fire as expected.

I'd like to get a list of recurring jobs (like shown in the dashboard). I've tried:

```
var api = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();
var joblist = api.ScheduledJobs(0, 100);
```

but the `joblist` is always empty (count = 0);

Comment: I would look at the code for the dashboard page; it's all on their GitHub: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/Dashboard/Pages/RecurringJobsPage.cshtml

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer, instead of using "ScheduledJobs" use "ProcessingJobs", which will display all the scheduled job.

```
var api = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();
var processing = api.ProcessingJobs(0, 200);
```